# How Dump automatic variable in VCD

Tags: system-verilog

The automatic variable written inside module in systemverilog donot dumping in VCD.How dump automatic variable in VCD?

```
module xyz();

    function automatic logic [1:0] get_size;
    input logic [7:0] a;
          logic [1:0] b;
    b[1:0] = (2'11 & {2{(a[7:0]==8'hff)}});
    return b[1:0];
endfunction
endmodule
```

Comment: Assign static variables with the values of the automatic variables, otherwise cannot be done with standard VCD as described by IEEE-Std 1800. Some vendors have their own waveform format that can display automatic variables. If you are ambitious, write your own VPI / DPI and custom waveform format.

Answer (score 0):

Dumping of automatic variables is not supported. This is because there can be many active copies of an automatic function or task, and there's no easy way to represent which copy a variable belongs to. Also, waveforms expect variables to exist for the entire life of the simulation.

Some examples showing the difficulties

```
assign o = get_size(w,x) + get_size(y,z);
```

or

```
task automatic do(
    input logic [7:0] a,
    output logic [1:0] b);
   #10 b = a;
endtask
initial fork
       #1 do(1,x);
       #2 do(2,y);
        join
```